# Count Records from One Column WHERE values are different

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, counting

I'm fairly new to SQL-server and stack overflow, so forgive me if my question is misworded, or naive.

I tried searching but couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.

I have a table with a column *unique identifier* `(varchar 50)`, and another *column1* of `INT` which has values of 1, 2, 3, or 4. I am trying to create a `SELECT` resultset which `COUNT`s all of the records which have values less than 4 in *column1* and another `COUNT` which returns the number of records where *column1* equals 4. Is it possible to create this resultset in one query?

Ideally, I'd like my resultset to look like the following:

```
Total Records       Records w/ *column1* < 4             Records w/ *column1* = 4
===========           ==================                     ================
   1000                      850                                    150
```

After completing some searches, I've tried the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(unique_id) 'Total'
, COUNT(CASE
WHEN column1 = 4 THEN '1'
ELSE '0' 
END) AS 'Records w/ 4'
, COUNT(CASE
WHEN column1 < 4 THEN '1'
ELSE '0'
END) AS 'Records < 4'
FROM mytable
;
```

Which returns a result set where 'Record w/ 4' and 'Total' both equal the same number.

Comment: Did you try to change the second `COUNT()` with `SUM()`? Also do not use the number as character ('1') instead use `1`

Comment: I would also replace the third `COUNT()` with `SUM()`.

Comment: Why sum?  I am not sure he wants a sum of the columns.  Maybe I'm missing something. 150 records = 4 will sum to 600, not 150.

Comment: @TinyHaitian Because `COUNT` will also count the 0s.  With `SUM`, adding 0s will not increase your number.  You can try it yourself, see if `COUNT` works or not.

Comment: Ah, I reread his query.   Got it now.  Still needs tweaking.  I'll reassess on my end.

Comment: I took the time to read the suggestions and query, and agree with them.   http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/620a2/8/0

Comment: Thanks everyone, when I tried Sami's suggestion my original query worked. I also tried Arulmouzhi's code below, which worked as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 'Total'
, SUM(CASE WHEN column1 = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Records w/ 4'
, SUM(CASE WHEN column1 < 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Records < 4'
FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just looking for a simple conditional aggregation as

```
SELECT COUNT(1) Total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Value < 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) LessThan4,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Value = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) EqualTo4,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Value > 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) MoreThan4
FROM
(
  VALUES
  (1, 1),
  (2, 2),
  (3, 3),
  (4, 4),
  (5, 5)
) T(Id, Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using `sum()` for this purpose, but you can also use `count()`.  Your method doesn't work because `count()` counts the number of non-`NULL` values -- and both the `then` and `else` return non-`NULL` values.

So, you can also do:

```
SELECT COUNT(unique_id) as Total,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN column1 = 4 THEN 1 END) AS Records_eq_4,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN column1 < 4 THEN 1 END) AS Records_lt_4,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN column1 > 4 THEN 1 END) AS Records_gt_4
FROM mytable;
```

Note that I renamed the columns so they don't need to be escaped.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.